# wordpress function and PHP strtoupper (should be quick)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a custom site theme for a client who wants the site in wordpress.

The menu area is being populated by the pages they make in WP via:

```
<?php  wp_nav_menu(); ?>
```

I want to keep the menu text all in caps. Ive tried the standard strtoupper like so

```
<?php  strtoupper(wp_nav_menu()); ?>
```

but nothing happens. Is there a way I should do this? Honestly im not sure if its possible since ***wp_nav_menu*** is a wordpress function.

I dont think its too professional for me to tell them "hey when your creating the page titles, keep em all in caps" lol..so yeah

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add in the menu CSS this:

```
text-transform:uppercase;
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know WP, but `wp_nav_menu()` doesn't return anything so you cannot do a `strtoupper()` on it. You CAN change the WP function to add the `strtoupper()` function, but why not do it simply by using `CSS`?

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```